# Xcode not opening text files c++

Tags: c++, xcode

Hey Ive been trying to pen a text file called "Text.txt" in Xcode and it isnt working.

This is the code I have been running:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("Text.txt");

    if(!myfile.is_open()){
        cout<<"File Not Opened"<<endl;
    }

    myfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

And this is my folder structure:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: And where is this `Text.txt` file located? More precisely, where is it located to the working directory of the program when you run it? When running a program from an IDE, the programs working directory might not be what you expect it to be. Consider checking the run settings to make sure the working directory is set to the directory where the file is located.

Comment: Never used XCode for C++, but I'd expect any sane IDE to run executables either from bin folder (here `Products`) or from project root.Try both of these locations and see which one is working.

Answer (score -2):

`Text.txt` needs to be located in the same folder as `xcodeproj`.

If it still does not work, just write some file with `std::ofstream` and see where it will be written. This will be the same folder as the one from which you need to read.

If you start your executed program directly from Terminal, the current Terminal Directory from which you start will determine the read directory.